# How to Select A number of data of table record, but before apply a condition on this record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want that in my wen site admin can confirm dis active users. for this, I want show dis active users in repeater to admin.
I want the Disactive user repeater has paging.
for this purpose I write this Procedure in SQL:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SPFetchAllDisActiveUser]
(
@StartRowIndex int,
@MaxRows int
)
as
Begin

Select * From 
  (select *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [User-ID] asc) AS RowNum 
   from [User-Tbl]
  ) As DisActiveUser
Where RowNum between @StartRowIndex+1 and @MaxRows
 and [Gu-Id] is null;
END
```

I know that (for example if `@StartRowIndex=0` and `@MaxRows=10`) this code first select 10 record from table and so check that if an record has condition `[Gu-Id]` is `null`, return it.
I want that first apply condition next select a number rows from it. but I don't know how to do it.
I Thanks anybody that guide me :)

Comment: "I want my website admin to confirm inactive users.  So, I plan to show a list of inactive users in a repeater control.  I want the "inactive user" repeater to use paging.  So, I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL.

Comment: Can't you just move the `[Gu-Id] IS NULL` to the inner select?

Comment: I test it. don't work. Select * From 
   (select (select * from [User-Tbl] where [Gu-Id] is null)
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [User-ID] asc) AS RowNum from [User-Tbl]) As DisActiveUser
    Where RowNum between @StartRowIndex+1 and @MaxRows;

Comment: I think @MichaelMcGriff means just add 'Where [Gu-Id] is null' right before ') As DisActiveUser' -- that looks good to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment about moving the `[Gu-Id] IS NULL`, try this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SPFetchAllDisActiveUser]
(
    @StartRowIndex INT,
    @MaxRows INT
)
AS

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [User-ID] ASC) AS RowNum 
    FROM [User-Tbl]
    WHERE [Gu-Id] IS NULL
) AS DisActiveUser
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @StartRowIndex + 1 AND @MaxRows;

END
```